# Serialization: size of char and uint32_t

Tags: c, networking, serialization

I have multiple questions.

1. Is the size of char always 1 (Byte) on every system ?
2. Is the size of uint32_t always 4 (Byte) on every system ?

I wrote two little functions to serialize my struct, but I can't tell if this is a good way to do it.

```
struct udtpackage{
    char version;
    bool eof;
    uint32_t data_size;
    uint32_t encrypted_size;
    char data[BUFFERSIZE+16];
    char hmac[64];
};

void serialize (udtpackage package, unsigned char* buffer){
    uint32_t tmp;

    memcpy(&buffer[0], &package.version, 1);
    (package.eof) ? (buffer[1] = 0xFF) : (buffer[1] = 0x00);
    tmp = htonl(package.data_size);
    memcpy(&buffer[2], &tmp, 4);
    tmp = htonl(package.encrypted_size);
    memcpy(&buffer[6], &tmp, 4);
    memcpy(&buffer[10], &package.data[0], BUFFERSIZE+16);
    memcpy(&buffer[10+BUFFERSIZE+16], &package.hmac[0], 64);
}

void deserialize (udtpackage* package, unsigned char* buffer){
    uint32_t tmp;

    memcpy(&package->version, &buffer[0], 1);
    (buffer[1] & 0xFF) ? (package->eof = true) : (package->eof = false);
    memcpy(&tmp, &buffer[2], 4);
    package->data_size = ntohl(tmp);
    memcpy(&tmp, &buffer[6], 4);
    package->encrypted_size = ntohl(tmp);
    memcpy(&package->data[0], &buffer[10], BUFFERSIZE+16);
    memcpy(&package->hmac[0], &buffer[10+BUFFERSIZE+16], 64);
}
```

Comment: C defines "byte" as the size of a char. It's not necessarily 8 bits, though.

Comment: `(package.eof) ? (buffer[1] = 0xFF) : (buffer[1] = 0x00)` is stupid. Just do `buffer[1] = package.eof ? 0xFF : 0x00`.

Comment: @LPs No. On some DSPs, `sizeof (uint32_t)` is `1` as `CHAR_BIT` is 32.

Comment: @LPs But yes, if it exists, `uint32_t` always occupies four octets.

Comment: @FUZxxl Thank you. I learned something today. ;)

Comment: @LPs Pleae don't delete your comment. It made my reply very hard to understand.

Comment: Serializing this way using `memcpy()` will preserve the endianness of the platform that did the serialization, that's not always optimal. Also, it might not be top-performing if the calls don't get inlined.

Comment: @unwind It's very likely that `memcpy` is inlined unless OP is using a shit compiler.

Comment: @FUZxxl: Systems with `CHAR_BIT != 8` don't have octets (resp. the term does not make sense on such systems), but still might provide `uint16_t` or `uint32_t`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. Yes. The size of char is always 1. That doesn't mean that there are 8 bits per byte though.
2. No. For example, the implementation may define 32 bits per byte,
   then the size of uint32_t will be 1. If this is the case, some of the fixed width types will not be defined.

Here is a potential problem:

```
memcpy(&buffer[2], &tmp, 4);    
                         ^
```

As I mentioned in the second point, the code should be:

```
memcpy(&buffer[2], &tmp, sizeof(tmp));
                         ^
```

Going further the buffer offsets should be fixed as well, otherwise you will potentially waste memory:

```
memcpy(&buffer[6], &tmp, 4);
               ^
```